# Retrieving the property name as a string jSon jQuery

Tags: jquery, json

```
    var days = new Array("sun", "mon", "tue", "wed", "thu", "fri", "sat");

    $.each(data, function (i, object) {    
        $.each(object, function (property, value) {
            var propertyString = getPropertyAsString(property);
            if ($.inArray(propertyString, days) != -1)
            {
                // do something
            }
            count++;
        });
    });
```

Above is the code stub that I'm using to retrieve data from json using jQuery. What I want to do is get the "`property` name" (I've marked it using `getPropertyAsString()` inside the nested `$.each()` as a string that I then want to check if this "property name" exists in days array or not.

To be more specific, below is the json:

```
[{
    "STID": 0,
    "VRNO": 0,
    "VRNOA": 0,
    "VRDATE": "\/Date(-62135596800000)\/",
    "PARTY_ID": null,
    "BILTY_NO": null,
    "BILTY_DATE": "\/Date(-62135596800000)\/",
    "RECEIVED_BY": null,
    "TRANSPORTER_ID": null,
    "REMARKS": null,
    "Year_srno": 0,
    "ETYPE": null,
    "NAMOUNT": 0,
    "UID": 0,
    "ORDER_VRNO": 0,
    "FREIGHT": 0,
    "PARTY_ID_CO": null,
    "SALEBILLNO": 0,
    "DISCP": 0,
    "DISCOUNT": 0,
    "CURRENCY_ID": 0,
    "EXPENSE": 0,
    "COMPANY_ID": 0,
    "VEHICLE_ID": null,
    "PARTY_NAME": null,
    "isEditted": false,
    "isDeleted": false,
    "isNew": false,
    "Mon": "0",
    "Tue": "0",
    "Wed": "0",
    "Thu": "500",
    "Fri": "0",
    "Sat": "0",
    "Sun": "0"
}]
```

What I'm trying to do is get the values of the week days at the end i.e. Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri, Sat, Sun

I've been trying and trying and can't find the way to do it. Kindly please suggest me if there's a way around it.

Comment: Also when I try `Console.log(property)`, the name does show up in the console but I am not able to use it in the above code, I have tried `property.toString()` as well but can't get the expected result :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `property` variable in your example is already a string, you don't need to convert it.

The actual problem is that the weekday names in the object are capitalized ("Mon", "Tue") but the `days` array has them in lower case ("mon", "tue"). If `days` is something you can edit, just change it to match the object keys, or use `.toLowerCase()` with the key you're comparing them to.

```
if ($.inArray(property.toLowerCase(), days) != -1)
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/PHDPp/

Answer (score -1):

If i got your question the right way, you can get the value of days and log them like this:

```
for(i in days){
    console.log(days[i]+': '+yourJson[i])
}
```

if i got it wrong pleas tell me